# t-statistic varies widely when used for bootstrap sampling process

Tags: python, t-test, sampling, bootstrap, two-sample

I have two samples of size 20 and I want to see if the difference between the geometric means is significant using two-sample t-statistic and bootstrap sampling.

Here is what I'm doing

```
# assume we have sample_A and sample_B and number of repetitions for bootstrap sampling is 100

num_repetitions = 100

# sample_A
sample_A_geometric_means = []

for i in range(num_repetitions):
   # randomly sample from sample_A with replacement and the same size 
   s = np.random.choice(sample_A, size=len(sample_A))
   
   # calculate geometric mean
   geom_mean = geometric_mean(s)
  
   sample_A_geometric_means.append(geom_mean)

# do the same for sample_B and get sample_B_geometric_means

# calculate the two-sample t-statistic with sample_A_geometric_means and sample_B_geometric_means

t_stat = two_sample_t_test(sample_A_geometric_means, sample_B_geometric_means)
```

If I run this multiple times with different random seeds, geometric means vary a lot as I'm using bootstrap sampling. This in turn makes t-stat vary quite widely. Sometimes it is less than 2 but other times is greater than 4.

1. How should I reconcile this? What t-stat value should I be reporting? If every time I run this and get a very different t-stat value, what does it say about the process?
2. Is there another method to show if the difference between the geometric means of the two samples significant?

Comment: (1) $B = 100$ bootstrap re-samples may not be enough for stable bootstrap results. (2) I wonder why you're using t statistic for a bootstrap of _geometric_ means. (3) You don't say anything about your data, but geometric means are only for non-negative data. (4) Partly on theoretical grounds and partly based on experience, I prefer to use bootstraps for CIs, and permutation tests for testing hypotheses. It seems to me you're mainly interested in a test. // Is this a course assignment in which the method is specified, or a practical application in which you're free to choose methods?

Comment: I'm using geometric means because the samples represent collection of annual returns of a portfolio. For example - returns for each year between 1981-2000. At the end of the day I want to compare and see if annualized return for this period (geometric mean of 20 yearly returns) for two strategies is significantly different or not. No this is not a course assignment. I'm free to chose any method.

Comment: Regarding using B = 100, I can use 1000 but I see a similar behavior. Also, the t-stat jumps in the range of 7-11.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on which other metric could be used?

Comment: Yes. Ratio of geometric means. See my answer just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can start by showing you a permutation test for the
ratio of the geometric means of two samples of size 20 from
two different gamma populations (which, of course, have positive
support).

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rgamma(20, 5, .10)
x2 = rgamma(20, 5, .2)

boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

The respective geometric means are $42.06$ and $24.70.$ Their ratio
is `rto.obs`, $1.703.$
Because it seems natural to look at ratios of geometric means,
the question is whether $1.703$ is significantly different from $1$
(2-sided test) at the 5% level of significance.

```
g1 = prod(x1)^.05;  g2 = prod(x2)^.05
g1; g2
[1] 42.06336
[1] 24.69576
rto.obs = g1/g2;  rto.obs
[1] 1.703262
```

Possibly, one could derive the the distribution of the ratio
of gamma geometric means to find an exact test. Instead, I will
repeatedly scramble the $n_1+n_2 = 40$ observations into two
permuted samples each with $n_i = 20$ observations, find the two
geometric means, and then their ratio. After doing this $B = 10\,000$ times, I will have $B$ ratios, which can give me a good idea of
the distribution of the ratio. Finally, comparing this simulated
permutation distribution of ratios with the observed ratio $1.703,$
I can see whether or not the observed ratio is unusually far from $1.$

```
set.seed(602)
x = c(x1, x2)
B = 10000;  rto.prm = numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
 x.prm = sample(x)
 rto.prm[i] = prod(x.prm[1:20])^.05/prod(x.prm[21:40])^.05
 }
mean(rto.prm/rto.obs > .975 | rto.obs/rto.prm < .025)
[1] 0.0047  # P-value of sim permutation test.

hdr = "Simulated Dist'n of Ratios of Geometric Means"
hist(rto.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v=rto.obs);abline(v=1/rto.obs)
```

[image]